# SignalR and ticker service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I was wonderign if anyone has a good example on how to construct a SignalR Hub, so multiple clients will not cause multiple broadcast messages to be sent out?

Basically, I have a status message I'd like to broadcast to every connected client. Currently, every client causes me a new message to be broadcast, so if my ticker is say 4 times a minute and I have 5 clients, the Hub starts sending 20 updates a minute, and each client receives all 20 messages instead of 4 for all of them.

Comment: Are you telling the hub to send the message from the client?

Comment: No, Client only register to receive messages.

Comment: Can you add some code to look at please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found excellent article on this very subject: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr

Comment: FYI The link has moved. VS2012 version is here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr and the VS2013 version is: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20